# How to translate table defintion from MS Access to Oracle using C# and OleDbConnection?

Tags: c#, oracle, ms-access, etl, oracle.manageddataaccess

I need to copy a table from MS Access to Oracle without using OracleBulkCopy (using Managed Data Access).
First step is to create the table.

As can be seen in the code below I am now converting the fields manually while querying for the column length.

I would like to use a statement that converts the fields for me without having to add rules for all types manually since there are a lot of types.
Or better, just extract some sort of DDL that I can execute in Oracle.
Is this possible?

```
            private int GetLength(string accessTableName, string columnName, OleDbConnection accessConnection)
            {
                columnName = $"[{columnName}]";
                var accessCommand = new OleDbCommand($"select max(len({columnName})) from {accessTableName}", accessConnection);
                return int.Parse(accessCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            }

            private void CreateEmptyTable(DataTable schemaTable, string tableName, OracleConnection oracleConnection, string accessTableName, OleDbConnection accessConnection)
            {
                var columnSpecs = new string[schemaTable.Rows.Count];
                for (int i = 0; i < schemaTable.Rows.Count; ++i)
                {
                    var name = schemaTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                    var dataType = schemaTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[5];
                    //var length = schemaTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[2];
                    var length = GetLength(accessTableName, name.ToString(), accessConnection);

                    var precision = schemaTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[3];
                    var scale = schemaTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[4];

                    var oracleDt = "";
                    switch (dataType.ToString())
                    {
                        case "System.String":
                            oracleDt = $"nchar({length})";
                            break;
                        case "System.Int32":
                        case "System.Int16":
                            var iLng = int.Parse(length.ToString()) * 2;
                            oracleDt = $"number({iLng},0)";
                            break;
                        case "System.Double":
                        case "System.Decimal":
                            oracleDt = $"number({length},{precision})";
                            break;
                        default:
                            throw new Exception();
                    }

                    name = name.ToString().ToUpper().Replace(' ', '_');

                    columnSpecs[i] = $"{name} {oracleDt}";
                }

                var query = $"create table MDB_{tableName.ToUpper().Replace(' ', '_')} ( {string.Join(",", columnSpecs)} )";

                var oracleCommand = new OracleCommand(query, oracleConnection);
                oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Comment: Access does not have any built-in tool which generates DDL, especially a dialect that's compatible with Oracle.  Short answer: No.

Comment: Data type `nchar` seems to be a bad choice. When you use `CHAR(x)` then string is padded with space characters, I doubt that is what you want. Nowadays `NCHAR` and `NVARCHAR2` are typically useless as the default character set in database is `AL32UTF8`, i.e. UTF-8. Use simple `VARCHAR2` instead.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thanks, I didn't know that this caused the padding. Will use the varchar2 datatype.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you try executing the command on the base table in place of the query.

So try something like this:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "ODBC Database", strCon,
           acTable, "tblHotels2", "tblHotelEXPORT", True
```

Now above is from Access, but your posted answer is on the right track.

When I send above to SQL server, long, money, memo, text files all get sent out and created on sql server. I suppose you could use above, and then execute a series of alter table to change the types, but that would be painful.

So before the pain approach, I would try above. Note that:
I used the transfer command on the base table, not a query.
I used "True" as that last value - that means no data copy, just structure.

You could also try/test a different ORACLE odbc driver. I don't have a test oracle server around, but sending the above to SQL server - it did a VERY nice job of creating the data types on the server side.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I need. I will see if I can reproduce this with C# and Oracle. In my last try all the fields were varchar2, but maybe there is some parameter that I didn't look at.

Answer (score 0):

This option uses Interop instead but the result is disappointing. Numeric fields are converted to VARCHAR2, haven't tested other types yet. Note that it also requires a DSN file, and it requires the Oracle ODBC drivers.

For the people who could use this, here is the code:

```
public void CreateTableDefsUsingInterop(string accessFilePath, string accessTable, string oracleUser, string oraclePassword, string oracleTable, string oracleDSNFilePath)
{
    var strConn = $"ODBC;FILEDSN={oracleDSNFilePath};UID={oracleUser};PWD={oraclePassword}";
    var sTypExprt = "ODBC Database";

    var interop = new Application();
    interop.OpenCurrentDatabase(accessFilePath);
    var db = interop.CurrentDb();
    var emptyTable = $"n{accessTable}";
    QueryDef qd;

    qd = db.CreateQueryDef("access2ora1", $"select top 1 * into [{emptyTable}] from [{accessTable}]");
    qd.Execute();

    qd = db.CreateQueryDef("access2ora2", $"delete from [{emptyTable}]");
    qd.Execute();

    interop.DoCmd.TransferDatabase(AcDataTransferType.acExport, sTypExprt, strConn, AcObjectType.acTable, emptyTable, oracleTable);

    interop.Quit(AcQuitOption.acQuitSaveNone);
}
```